# Synonymize [user-rank] to [top-users] and [rankings] to [reputation-leagues]

Tags: discussion, meta, synonym-request

Both the tags [rankings](/questions/tagged/rankings) and [user-rank](/questions/tagged/user-rank) seem to describe the same thing as either [top-users](/questions/tagged/top-users) or [reputation-leagues](/questions/tagged/reputation-leagues).

Since the tags pertain to approximately the same concept **I think they should be considered together!**

**Currently:**

1. [reputation-leagues](/questions/tagged/reputation-leagues) has **265** questions, has [an outdated wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/reputation-leagues/info) by today's standards. It would be better served by writing a new wiki taking from the [rankings wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/rankings/info) and focusing it exclusively on the [leagues page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/year/meta).
2. [top-users](/questions/tagged/top-users) has **98** questions. Has a good wiki that should be focused and contain a link to [reputation-leagues](/questions/tagged/reputation-leagues). It should be focused to be about all the ranking's questions except those of the [reputation-league](/questions/tagged/reputation-league).
3. [rankings](/questions/tagged/rankings) has **39** questions, has a good tag wiki. However, most questions on the tag are not about the [reputation-leagues](/questions/tagged/reputation-leagues) page but are about the top-user ([top-users](/questions/tagged/top-users)) list of the tag pages.
4. [user-rank](/questions/tagged/user-rank) has **19** questions, has no tag wiki. All the questions on the tag are about [reputation-leagues](/questions/tagged/reputation-leagues).

**Action that could be taken:**

The [synonyms page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) has no hits for the word "rank" and in the [tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) there are only 2 hits for the word "rank", those are [rankings](/questions/tagged/rankings) and [rankings](/questions/tagged/rankings).

Since the word "rank" is intuitive these tags should be made synonyms to keep the results in both the tags and synonyms page's search.

The most seamless solution would likely be:

- Synonymize [user-rank](/questions/tagged/user-rank) -> [reputation-leagues](/questions/tagged/reputation-leagues)
- Synonymize  [rankings](/questions/tagged/rankings) -> [top-users](/questions/tagged/top-users)

This solution would require almost no retags, but I somehow think the wording of [user-rank](/questions/tagged/user-rank) would make a better fit to [top-users](/questions/tagged/top-users) and the wording of [rankings](/questions/tagged/rankings) would make a better fit for [reputation-leagues](/questions/tagged/reputation-leagues). (I don't know if the tooling allows this switch.)